# Lazy loading SwiftUI Grid on both vertical and horizontal direction

Tags: ios, swift, gridview, swiftui

As the title says I try to build a Grid view that loads lazily on both vertical and horizontal, the main goal is building a calendar for a list of employee, both the list and the calendar interval can be very large so they have to be rendered lazily. I've tried `LazyHGrid` and `LazyVGrid` but they only render views lazily on one direction. The further approach uses one `LazyVStack` for the whole view and one `LazyHStack` for each row, the loading is lazily (check print in the console) but while scrolling the views loses their position and the grid get's broken

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 20, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                Section(header: columnHeaders) {
                    ForEach(0..<20) { row in
                        LazyHStack(spacing: 20, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                            Section(header: rowHeader(with: "Employee \(row)")) {
                                ForEach(0..<100) { column in
                                    Text("Cell \(row), \(column)")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .font(.largeTitle)
                                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                                        .background(Color.red)
                                        .onAppear {
                                            print("Cell \(row), \(column)")
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var columnHeaders: some View {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 20, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
            Section(header: rowHeader(with: "")) {
                ForEach(0..<100) { column in
                    Text("Header \(column)")
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
                        .background(Color.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func rowHeader(with label: String) -> some View {
        Text(label)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .background(Color.white)
    }
    
}
```

[image]

PS: I also need fixed headers, that is achieved in the code above using `pinnedViews`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the out-of-alignment problem by using a pair of nested single-axis ScrollViews instead of one multi-axis ScrollView.